# Why is my MacBook Pro not charging?

Tags: mac, macbook, battery

I have a MacBook Pro. The battery icon said I only have 1% and when I right click, it said 'Battery is not charging' and Power source: Power Adapter.

Is that a software configuration to set the battery charging when I plug in? Or something else is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find yourself an Apple Store, show them the issue, they may replace the battery right there if it's in warranty and the battery is easily removed (unlike the newest line of MacBook Pros).  I've had them swap out my battery on an out of warranty machine too.

I believe the basic test for you is:

1. Apple Menu >> About this Mac
2. Click More Info
3. Find the section for power/battery
4. If the age of the battery is less than a year and the charge count (cycles) is less than 300, they have often replaced the battery on your reported symptom.

Of course, Apple has a fancy battery testing tool that they will reboot your computer into once you're there in person, so I *implore* you to find an Apple Store, an Apple Certified tech who won't charge you for warranty repair, or contact Apple Directly about the issue.

For more info on what counts as a "cycle" read this http://www.apple.com/batteries/

Similar issue discussed on Apple's Discussion forums: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1296373

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally my 3 year old BlackBook will do that - the cable is plugged in, but the battery isn't charging. My solution - unplug the cord, plug it in again, and wait a few seconds. If it starts charging, then I leave it. If it hasn't, I do that process again. Tedious, but it works.

Comment: I see the same issue, and have the same solution, for my with my ~3 year old MacBook. Always assumed it was a hardware issue (magnetic connector not quite connecting).

Comment: I had this too. Turns out it wasn't the connector, but there is a chip on the inside of the Macbook that was blown, replaced for about $60USD or so.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some days ago.I did not know what to do but since i was travelling i just packed everything and went away.Some hours later i plugged the cable again and it started charging again as usual.It happened to me a second time but this time it started to charge sooner than the first time.In both occacion that happened when i let run the battery below 2%.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the SMC or the PMU: [Apple KB Article HT1411.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1411) Don't know what year your MacBook Pro is, but if the battery is dead, it might be covered under warrenty or replacement. Also [calibrate your battery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490) for long life.

Comment: "Calibrating" does not increase the lifespan of a Lithium ion battery, but resetting the SMC/PMU is the only thing you can do at home. If that doesn't work, take it in.

Comment: I've recalibrated numberous batteries and extended their lifespans, just like many other users, and the documents report, as well. You know something that the engineers don't?

Answer (score 1):

MacBook Pro (set to Show->Time on battery settings) had the same "Not Charging" problem. It was solved by the above "My solution - unplug the cord, plug it in again, and wait a few seconds.". As the author suggested, I had to do this several times.
I have also found that the condition can be prevented by disconecting the power and waiting until the battery time left is calculated before I close (sleep) the MacBook Pro, then restart the Mac Book Pro on battery only again waiting until the display has calculated the time left on the battery.  Once that calculation is achieved the Mac Book Pro power adapter can be reconnected without creating the bug that leaves the Mac Book Pro in "Not Charging" mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I didn't want to go and replace the charger unless absolutely necessary. I inspected the cables and didn't notice any damage on any part of the cable or charger. As a final measure I decided to try and clean the contacts and the magsafe power socket. This did the trick!

It appears that the charging socket has a low tolerance for dirt, grime or debris. I took a cotton tip and dipped it in a solvent such as mentholated spirits and wiped the gold-plated contacts of both the plug and socket. Make sure there's no dirt there stopping the plug fitting as if it were brand new.

Once its clean it should work as new! Anyway worked for me and I didn't have to fork out for a new charger :)

Answer (score 0):

The MacBook likely believes there's a power source plugged in because there could still be electricity passing through that line that the MacBook can detect, although the power source itself may not be functioning correctly (sending a powerful enough current) and charging the battery.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I charge my macbook pro?

Comment: The power source *is* probably plugged in, right?